# Restsharp 110.2 returns 401 with Basic Authentication

Tags: .net, get, basic-authentication, restsharp, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to figure out how to do a very simple GET call with RestSharp (v.110.2, the latest one by now) using Basic Authentication.
With Postman, everything is ok.

This is how I am creating the client object and doing the call:

```
    private static readonly string JOB_STATUS_URL = "jobStatus";
    private RestClient client;

    private void InizializeClient()
    {
        if (client == null)
        {
            string baseUrl = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CarteBaseUrl"];
            string usr = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CarteUsername"];
            string pwd = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CartePwd"];

            var options = new RestClientOptions(baseUrl)
            {
                Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(usr, pwd)
            };
            client = new RestClient(options);
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CheckSiStatus()
    {
        PorfolioDB db = new PorfolioDB();

        try
        {
            InizializeClient();
            var request = new RestRequest(JOB_STATUS_URL)
                .AddParameter("name", "test")
                .AddParameter("xml", "Y");
            var response = client.Get<JobStatusResponse>(request);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                error = e.Message
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

I have already checked all the other similar posts.

Any suggestion?

Thank you!